# Proving $(x^2 - y^2) = (x + y)(x-y)$

Tags: solution-verification, field-theory

I am trying to prove from the field axioms that $(x^2 - y^2) = (x+y)(x-y)$. I am going to take for granted the definition of subtraction as the addition of a negation and that $x(-y) = (-x)y = -(xy)$. Here is my attempt.

We have:
\begin{align*}
(x+y)(x-y) & = x(x-y) + y(x-y) & & \text{distributive law} \\
& = x(x + (-y)) + y(x + (-y)) & & \text{definition of subtraction} \\
& = (xx + x(-y)) + (yx + y(-y)) & & \text{distributive law} \\
& = (x^2 + (-(xy))) + (yx + (-y^2)) & & \text{uniqueness of additive inverse; definition of square} \\
& = (x^2 + (-(yx))) + (yx + (-y^2)) & & \text{commutativity of multiplication} \\
& = (x^2 + \left(-(yx) + yx \right) + (-y^2) & & \text{associativity of addition} \\
& = (x^2 + 0) + (-y^2) & & \text{additive inverse axiom} \\
& = x^2 + (-y^2) & & \text{additive identity axiom} \\
& = x^2 - y^2 & & \text{definition of subtraction} 
\end{align*}
How does this look?

Comment: It souds good. Well done!

Comment: This looks fine, except that "real-analysis" is not an appropriate tag.

Comment: @lulu: My apologies. What would be an appropriate tag? I'll fix it.

Comment: I'd say "abstract-algebra" or "field-theory".

Comment: In your 4th line, you write: $\ = (x^2 + (-(xy))) + (yx + (-y^2))\quad \text{uniqueness of additive inverse; definition of square}, \\ $ but you could just as well write, $\ = (x^2 + (-(yx))) + (yx + (-y^2))\quad \text{uniqueness of additive inverse; definition of square}.\ $ This would bypass the commutativity step.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to approach it for the sake of curiosity:
\begin{align*}
x^{2} - y^{2} & = (x^{2} - xy) + (xy - y^{2})\\\\
& = x(x-y) + y(x - y)\\\\
& = (x+y)(x-y)
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Looks good overall. I do have one nitpick:

At least for me, it is typically not given that the additive inverse is unique in fields, or that $x(-y) = -(xy)$ for sure. (Or the more general $(-1)(xy) = (-x)y = x(-y)$.)

I believe that technically needs to be shown if you want to go from the axioms.